# Does spark.sql.functions.typedLit supports Map[String, Any]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a map of type `Map[String, String]` which i want to append within another map2 of type `Map[String, Any]`. Later this map2 will be added as a column in a dataframe.

When I try to add map2 as a column using `spark.sql.functions.typedLit`, it fails with error:

```
Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.mutalbe.HashMap Map...
```

Any suggestion to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL API does not support `Any` in the schema, so you get the same error as in the snapshot below while creating the `df3` . `Map` has to be one of the supported type by Spark SQL.

```
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(("foo", 1), ("bar", 2), ("baz", 3)).toDF("str", "num")

val map1 = Map("foo" -> 42, "bar" -> 3)
val df2 = df.withColumn("typedLit_map", typedLit(map1))

df2.show()

val map2: Map[String, Any] = Map("foo" -> 42, "bar" -> 3.14, "baz" -> "xyz")

val df3 = df.withColumn("typedLit_map", typedLit(map2))
```